# Hiding and showing <ul> and <li> on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show a few categories on my web page and their sub-categories as well. So I have arranged them in the form of `nested <ul> <li>` tags. I want the effect that only when a user clicks on one of the categories, all the sub-categories should become visible. Initially no sub-categories are visible.

---

*In the body part, I have done this*

```
<ul>
   <li class="dropdown">Data mining and data warehousing
      <ul>
           <li>Data mining techniques</li>
           <li>Knowledge discovery</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

    <li class="dropdown">Soft computing and artificial intelligence
       <ul>
            <li>Fuzzy systems</li>
            <li>Neural networks</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

*In the css part, I have done*

```
li.dropdown ul {
display : none;
}
```

---

*And I have added the following Javascript script in the head section of the html page*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
</script>
```

---

Initially, the effect works fine and all the sub categories are hidden. However, I want, say when I click on `Data mining and data warehousing`, then the two sub-categories should also become visible, which are `Data mining techniques` and `Knowledge discovery`.

---

Also, when I click on other category, the sub-categories of previously opened categories should collapse again. How can I do that ?

Comment: You should try to be convenient and prepare a JSfiddle ;)

Comment: @EricG In this particular case a jsFiddle would be meaningless, because the problem isn't with the code but with *when* it's executed; the default settings in jsFiddle will delay its execution until after the DOM has loaded and eliminate the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the idea is to hide everything but the clicked `li`, and then toggle subcategory visibility for the clicked one:

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
   $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
   $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nfXS/) with example.

Comment: Yups got it.. I was placing the javascript in the head section. It should be placed towards the end of the body tag !!

Comment: You can put it in the head just fine, but wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: @CSSS As tdammers said, you can put it in the head as long as you wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` call; that's pretty much the basis of jQuery coding, and is one of the very first concepts introduced in the tutorials, so you should go back and refresh yourself on how it works and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
   $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but the above amkes no difference. You mean the su-cateogaries should expand on clicking on the main cateogary, right ??

Comment: Yups got it.. I was placing the javascript in the head section. It should be placed towards the end of the body tag !!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
   $('.dropdown ul').hide();
    $(this).children('ul').show();
});
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/7NYhe/